# SQL server 2012. Exception: attempted to read or write protected memory (MS.VS.OLE.Interop)

Tags: sql-server, exception

I am more an end-user of SQL Server 2012. When I right click on a table name and select "Edit top 200 rows" menu item. I get this message:

```
 Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)
 Additional information:
   Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that 
   other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)
```

If I try to do the right click again, SQL server will stop working and close. I still can use SQL commands to insert or update database. I have been searching around for a solution, and found this link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/42b79da5-6f1e-4122-a2cb-00def87a1ae2/microsoftvisualstudiooleinterop-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-this-is-often-an?forum=visualstudiogeneral

But it still does not help me to understand clearly the cause or find the solution to the issue. Any help to resolve this problem is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @alroc If the feature is there, it should be usable. In my case, it has been perfectly usable and stable for 3 years and all of a sudden doesn't work anymore. "It's buggy, don't use it" is completely unacceptable.

Comment: I've heard the advice of "don't use the table designer, it's buggy" for at least the past 5 years. Just because it works *for you, most of the time* doesn't mean that it's not buggy. People *have* reported issues to Microsoft, but it's still not as reliable as using actual SQL to update your tables.

Answer (score 92):

Are you attempting to edit a SQL 2014 database with the 2012 version (or earlier) of SQL Management Studio?

You can determine the SQL version of your database by running this query against your master database:

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

I had the same problem and I was able to direct edit tables ('Edit Top 200') by installing and using SQL Server Management Studio 2014. Even if both your DB and Management Studio are version 2012, it might not hurt to upgrade Management Studio.

Comment: When you try "Edit 200 rows" option in SQL server 2014 database (version 12) with SQL Server Management Studio 2012 this happens. Simplest option is to start using Management studio 2014.

Comment: I installed sql server 2012 so how it was upgraded to 2014?

Comment: Thanks jboeke, you caught the right nerve. I am struggling to find out crash of SSMS 2012 on just edit a table, and forget that my old crash machine I  was using SSMS (?)2014. With new VM with SSMS2012 , it keep crashing. will update and know it will go. thanks.

Comment: This should be marked as answer.

Also the same happens when you try to edit Top 200 rows with SSMS 2014 on a SQL Server 2016.

Comment: I had both instance of 2012 and 2014 and I just didn't notice that I started the 2012... Thanks !

Comment: I installed latest version of SSMS (2017) and it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Same here. I tried 2012 and 2014 to connect to SQL server 2016 and I got the same error. I install 2017 and its work now.

Answer (score 7):

I have also faced the same issue. And I noticed one thing that if you are using SQL database newer then the SQL management studio version, You will received that message. To overcome this issue just install SQL management studio equal or greater then version of database. i.e if you have SQL 2012 then you need to install SQL management studio 2012 or 2014.

Comment: Good idea. . . except that I am using Windows 7 and SQL management studio 2016 won't install on Windows 7. Only on Windows 10. I don't want to upgrade right now to Windows 10 until they get a good Eudora solution to Google's certificate problem.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone experiences the same issue in **MS SQL SERVER** from a different scenario ( eg - creating new database diagram )

And if this happened after fully uninstalling **MS VISUAL STUDIO**

**Follow the Steps Below;**

1. Delete Folders **MSDesigners8** and **Visual Database Tools** from the paths below.

- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSDesigners8
- C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Visual Database
  Tools

2. Reinstall Visual Studio and Run **Repair Tools** from the Visual Studio Installer.

**This Will Regenerate the folders we removed above and will repair partial fragments**.

Now your SQL SERVER Database Diagrams should be working fine. Cheers :)

Answer (score -1):

I have found a solution which does not require restart. Go to:

```
C:\Users\<User Name>\AppData\Local\Temp
```

and delete all the files. Before deleting, close the SSMS window.

Comment: these answer doesn't relate at all