# SSMS 2012 crashes with mssqllocaldb table edit top 200 rows

Tags: ssms-2012

SQL Server Management Studio 2012

mssqllocaldb  database

When I right click on a table and select Edit Top 200 Rows I get this error:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

### Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (mscorlib)

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

SSMS then crashes.

It works just fine with databases attached to my SQLEXPRESS instance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL server 2012. Exception: attempted to read or write protected memory (MS.VS.OLE.Interop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265735/sql-server-2012-exception-attempted-to-read-or-write-protected-memory-ms-vs-o)

Comment: Beware! LocalDB 2014 upgrades silently on Windows 10 to 2016, and then SSMS 2014 crashes with LocalDB 2016.